# Android preferences page isn't displaying once clicked, how do I get this to work?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to create a preferences page that once an item is selected, it goes to the preference page for the app. When I click on the item, it doesn't work. Please can someone help me in finding out how to make this work? Here is the code:

Preference Java file:

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

Main Activity Java file specific code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Goes back to the home screen
    case R.id.item1:  Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSettingActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Preferences XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<EditTextPreference
    android:title="EditText"
    android:key="name"
    android:summary="Enter your name" />

<CheckBoxPreference 
    android:title="Vibrate"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="vibrateCheckbox"
    android:summary="Turn vibrate on or off"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that because you are passing the wrong context to the intent:

instead of this:

```
case R.id.item1:  Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSettingActivity.class);
```

write this:

```
case R.id.item1:  Intent i = new Intent(yourActivityName.this, UserSettingActivity.class);
```